# What is the exact difference between AddQueueMember and AgentLogin applications?

Tags: queue, voip, asterisk, agent

For example is there a difference between AddQueueMember(queue_name, SIP/XXXX) and AgentLogin(SIP/XXXX) which has a queuename in queues.conf as the following?

```
agents.conf
[agents]
agent => 1001,4321,Wayne Kerr

queues.conf
[queue1]
member => Agent/1001

extensions.conf
exten => 28,1,AgentLogin(1001)
exten => 29,1,Queue(queue1)
```

I mean can i do the same thing with only AddQueueMember() application without using AgentLogin()? 
Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `AgentLogin(interface)` agent with that interface will login on all queues that he is member of. Agent needs to place the call to system where he will stop at AgentLogin app until he hangs up. Which means that agent has permanent connection with server and call entering queue is connected instantly.

If you use `AddQueueMember(queuename,interface,...)` you just add interface to specified queue, so when caller comes to queue that interface is rang. You have to call RemoveQueueMember() when you don't want that member in queue anymore (outside working hours).

there is a difference, now it all depends on what you need and how would you like to accomplish that :D